# Why does my object appear flat when rendering?

Tags: rendering

I'm new to blender. I have an object that I want to export as png sequence or avi. However when I render it, the object is flat and dark. How do I fix this?

I placed the camera correctly as well. Below are screenshots:
This is how it looks like originally:

[image]

This is how it looks like in test render or even in real animation render, whether avi or png or jpg:

[image]

Comment: it's not a render, it's a mask

Comment: Hello. I changed the Mask to View and now there is a "RenderLayer" that appeared. However, same result, it is flat and the object turned to black.

Comment: check render layers and compositing nodes. if you can't find something wrong, upload your .blend and post the link. http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello again. I uploaded my blender file. I hope you can point me to the right direction. http://pasteall.org/blend/34644

Comment: Ooo! windows 10 preview :D

Comment: Yeah it is Windows 10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no light in your scene, add a sun, spot, point or anything to give some light
[image]

Comment: my pleasure :) welcome in blender!